# commands via VS, WHERE?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have VS 2010 express, but i can't find the VS cmd via Start -> MS VS 2010 Express. Where is it ?

Comment: "VS cmd" isn't a thing - can you be more specific what you mean?

Comment: @Kieren, `Visual Studio Command prompt` is a thing he is looking for. It is available with regular VS and looks like it is for Express edition.

Comment: I guessed but thought it worth establishing for sure; as you can there is an answer assuming he means Visual Studio itself

Answer (score 0):

For regular Visual Studio (not Express) the `cmd` tool is located into `MS Visual Studio 2010`->`Visual Studio tools` subfolder. Do you have such a subfolder?

Comment: I mean: i can't find it when i go to Start -> All Programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express -> ???? (there is no folder or file for VS cmd) I read that there should be a folder named tools which contains this, perhaps it is not inside of Express.

Comment: @drp, sorry for misunderstanding, changed the answer completely

Comment: How do i install this tools folder ?

Comment: @drp, it was installed during installation. If you do not have it then probably `VS Express` installer doesn't create such a menu.

Comment: Isn't there any way to create it ?, i need it for my bat files that work along graphic assembly.

Comment: %comspec% /k ""c:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\vcvarsall.bat"" x86

Comment: @drp, my comment above has `Target` specified by `cmd` shortcut. You can create your own windows shortcut if you have this file on your machine.

Comment: Yes, i know, but i don't have this file, anyway thx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Default installation is: "Start->All Programs ->Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Express" folder

For Example C# in Windows XP is located in => C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\vcsexpress.exe

Comment: C++ is located in the same folder => C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\VCExpress.exe